# Twilio texting phrase with response

Tags: c#, sms, twilio

I can not seem to find any documentation on the Twilio site about this. But we are using C# to find the body text of a responder.
We want to be able to get the incoming text message body and then send the user a message back if the phrase the send to us contains or matches the phrase we want.

Example:

User sends "Sweepstakes" to our number

We SMS response "Congratulations, please go to our desk to retrieve your prize. Code 2222"

Is there a way to get the user's body text from the SMS and send them a specific response back.  If so how?

Comment: Which API library are you using?

Comment: I believe we are using the RESTful api. We have a .ashx file for our back and forth.

Comment: Here is a list of the API libraries http://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries

Comment: ohp, sorry, we are using the twilio-csharp api.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

All you need to do is have the URL that you have set as your Twilio phone numbers SMS Request URL return some TwiML that looks like this:

```
<Response>
   <Sms>
        Congratulations, please go to our desk to retrieve your prize. Code 2222
   </Sms>
</Response>
```

The SMS TwiML verb will automatically bounce back the message to the number that sent the SMS.  You can either generate this XML yourself or you can use the Twilio .NET TwiML generator to do it for you.  (You can get the generator with the twilio-csharp project, or better yet install it as a [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/Twilio.TwiML/).)

If you want to access the incoming SMS messages body, Twilio sends it along with a bunch of other parameters as form data (http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request). It looks like you might be using an HTTP Handler to handle the requests Twilio is making when and SMS is sent to your Twilio number.  If that is the case, you can get those values inside of the ProcessRequest method.

If you Twilio is making its request as a GET:

```
string body = context.Current.Request.Querystring["body"]
```

Or if Twilio is making its request as a POST:

```
string body = context.Current.Request.Form["body"]
```

Hope that helps.

Devin